# UITableView returns wierd sizes

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Hi guys so i have been dealing with UITableViews in iOS recently. and my UITableView returns some weird results..

Some Photos to show

[Then The first cell is so big.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nluzX.png)

[Then the 2nd Cell looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d11HJ.png)

These all cells varies in different sizes..

And the code for the class is this

```
 import UIKit
    import FLAnimatedImage

    class ShotDetailTableViewController: UITableViewController {


      @IBOutlet weak var bgImageView: FLAnimatedImageView!

        @IBOutlet weak var viewsCount: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var likesCount: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var commentsCount: UILabel!

        @IBOutlet weak var avatarImageView: UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!

        @IBOutlet weak var reboundCount: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var attachmentCount: UILabel!

        @IBOutlet weak var tagsCollectionView: UICollectionView!
        @IBOutlet weak var reboundCollectionView: UICollectionView!
        @IBOutlet weak var attachmentCollectionView: UICollectionView!

        @IBOutlet weak var commentTableView: UITableView!

        var shots : [Shot] = [Shot]()
        var comments : [Comment] = [Comment]()
        var shot : Shot!

        var reboundPages = 1
        var attachmentPages = 1

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            title = shot.title

            bgImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: shot.imageUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "1"), options: .ContinueInBackground)

            viewsCount.text = "\(shot.viewsCount)"
            likesCount.text = "\(shot.likesCount)"
            commentsCount.text = "\(shot.commentCount)"

            avatarImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: shot.user.avatarUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "2"))

            usernameLabel.text = "\(shot.user.username)"
            descriptionLabel.text = "\(shot.description)"

            reboundCount.text = "\(shot.reboundCount)"
            attachmentCount.text = "\(shot.attachmentsCount)"

            commentTableView.delegate = self
            commentTableView.dataSource = self
            commentTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0;
            commentTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
            commentTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None

            let api = DribbleObjectHandler()
           api.loadComments(shot.commentsUrl, completion:didLoadComments)

          NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(true, forKey: "_UIConstraintBasedLayoutLogUnsatisfiable")
        }


   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if tableView == commentTableView {
         return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        } else {
         return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        }
    }

       override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
         super.viewWillAppear(animated)
            avatarImageView.clipsToBounds = true
            avatarImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 25

          self.commentTableView.reloadData()
        }

        func didLoadComments(comments : [Comment]){
          self.comments = comments
          self.commentTableView.reloadData()
        }

      // MARK: - Table view data source

      override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        if tableView == commentTableView {
          return 1
        } else {
          return 1
         }
        }

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
            if tableView == commentTableView {
              return comments.count
            } else {
            return super.tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: section)
            }
        }

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            if tableView == commentTableView {
             let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CommentCell

            // Configure the cell...
                let comment = comments[indexPath.row]

                //cell.nameLabel.text = comment.user.name
              //  cell.commentLabel.text = comment.body

                //cell.avatarImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: comment.user.avatarUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "2"))
                cell.avatarImageView.image = UIImage(named: "2")

                return cell

            } else {
              let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
              return cell
          }
      }
      override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

    }
```

When i implement heightForRowAtIndexPath the tableView gets really small
unfortunately i cant put more than 2 links.. so i cant show the picture
and i get no errors in the log

I tried to find questions related to this but could not really find much.

Thanks in Advance
Aryan

Answer (score 1):

Try instead of implementing `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath`, implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: @AryanKashyap You are either ignorant or you are not understanding the answer. You don't have `heightForRowAtIndexPath` in your data source delegate (the code you have shown), so "No.. It doesn't" is not an appropriate comment (not sure if the comment before has been deleted, if so, please apologize my rant).

Comment: I am  sorry about the rudeness i meant that i did try to implement it but it's still the same..

Comment: And When i implement heightForRowAtIndexPath i get another kind of error answer is edited

Comment: @the_critic is correct, for what you are trying to do you need the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method - can you show us how you previously implemented it.

Comment: The error went away it was just a constraint Ambiguity.. I Fixed it ..And before i used estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath and code inside it was same as heightForRowAtIndexPath..

Comment: Then The Table View becomes so small it looks something like this..  https://www.dropbox.com/s/jzj5vzhek7j84wa/Screen%20Shot%202016-03-08%20at%2023.54.06.png?dl=0

Comment: The Problem has been fixed.. Thanks for your support guys.